# Using onCreate Bundle savedInstanceState with wallpaper service? (Watchface)

Tags: java, android-studio, watch-face-api

Im in need of some help.
**Secondary Activity**
    package archtectsproductions.scriptpyandroidwearwatchface;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import static android.graphics.Color.BLUE;
import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;
import static android.graphics.Color.RED;


public class WatchfaceConfigActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private int mTextColor = 0xffffffff;

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_watchface_config);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();

    Button buttonOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup radioTextColor =
                    (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rGroup);
            int selectedId = radioTextColor.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (selectedId) {
                default:
                case R.id.rDarkpastel:
                    mTextColor = 0xffffffff;
                    break;
                case R.id.Notepad:
                        mTextColor = GREEN;
                    break;
                case R.id.rHarvenjark:
                        mTextColor = BLUE;
                    break;
                case R.id.rVibrant:
                        mTextColor = RED;
                    break;

            }
            sendParamsAndFinish();
        }
    });
}

// sends data through Google API
private void sendParamsAndFinish() {
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq =
            PutDataMapRequest.create("/watch_face_config_cliu");
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt("text_color", mTextColor);
    PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq);

    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

}
```

**MAIN**
    public class WatchFaceCLiuService extends
        CanvasWatchFaceService {
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL =
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new Engine();
}

private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;                
    private int mTextColor = 0xffffffff;
    private float offsetx = (float)(-50 + 100 * Math.random());
    private float offsety = (float)(-50 + 100 * Math.random());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);
        ...
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(WatchFaceCLiuService.this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {            
        ...
        canvas.drawText(ts1, tx1, ty1, mDigitalPaint);
        ...
    }

    private void releaseGoogleApiClient() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient,
                onDataChangedListener);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient,
            onDataChangedListener);
        Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(mGoogleApiClient).
            setResultCallback(onConnectedResultCallback);
    }

    private void updateParamsForDataItem(DataItem item) {
        if ((item.getUri().getPath()).equals("/watch_face_config_cliu")) {
            DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
            if (dataMap.containsKey("text_color")) {
                int tc = dataMap.getInt("text_color");
                mDigitalPaint.setColor(tc);
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private final DataApi.DataListener onDataChangedListener =
            new DataApi.DataListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
            for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
                if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                    DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
                    updateParamsForDataItem(item);
                }
            }

            dataEvents.release();
            if (isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode()) {
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    private final ResultCallback<DataItemBuffer>
            onConnectedResultCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DataItemBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataItemBuffer dataItems) {
            for (DataItem item : dataItems) {
                updateParamsForDataItem(item);
            }

            dataItems.release();
            if (isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode()) {
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult
        connectionResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_ID_UPDATE_TIME);
        releaseGoogleApiClient();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
}
```

I really need help, I'm bashing my head against a brick wall. this just doesn't work. it wont send int across at all. Ive followed a guide. Ive done my best it just wont send, does anyone know a better way? should I make a global? would that work better but I'm not sure how id do it as I seem limited on what code I can use in the canvas watchface service.

all I want Is to send an int from one activity to another. Using a watchface service not a companion. I want to learn. so if you do answer don't just paste the code straight out, unless its easier to just paste the code and I can follow it, and decipher it.

thank you for any help .

<-- old
While I understand how to make in java a simple app that saves the users selection of a radio button and then puts it over to a separate activity to, say, change the color of text, i have hit a point where im struggling to do so in android wear.

The reason being i cant Implement the following.

```
@overide
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Radiogroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.myyrad);
      Radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener()) { ....
```

the following cant be implemented on the wallpaper service?

is there any alternative? or do i have to go the extremely confusing googleapiclient route? any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved. Nothing wrong with the tutorial or my code. Studio was looking for a different android play service. Changed it in the gradel